# Localhost refused to connect Tibco spotfire

Tags: oracle, localhost, spotfire, tibco

I am currently using Tibco spotfire with oracle database running on local machine, it was running earlier fine but now its showing local;host refused to connect[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: A lot of things could be causing this. Check the windows service is running, check the application can communicate with the database (log files should tell you that), check that the application is using port 8080 (will be different if https is enabled)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the server is UP.
Check in windows services if Spotfire services are started
Check in the  TSS directory/ tomcat/logs /Catalina log if Spotfire  server is up

Comment: Raise a support case with Tibco if any further help is required.